# How many hats can be obtained with one question?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

What is the maximum number of hats that a user can earn by posting only one question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [on the road](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/on-the-road)
2. [bugdroid](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/bugdroid) or [not a cherry](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/not-a-cherry)
3. [got a tablet for christmas](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/got-a-tablet-for-christmas)
4. [30 minutes or less](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/30-minutes-or-less)
5. [business in the front, party in the back](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/business-in-the-front-party-in-the-back)
6. [kofia](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/kofia)
7. [werewolf hunter](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/werewolf-hunter)
8. [treasure hunter](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/treasure-hunter)

The answer is 8. I did not include [selfie](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/selfie) since that cannot be obtained by just posting one question. Earning 8 hats on one question is very, very unrealistic, but technically possible.

Comment: yes, there should be also an answer with positive score. +1

Comment: You can't get Solstice and Kofia on the same question. On the other hand, Tablet for Christmas + Kofia *is* possible due to timezone shenanigans.

Comment: I think you're missing one; theoretically, a question could earn Eureka! as well.